# Prove that Graph $(V \cup W,E^{\prime})$ is connected

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $(V,E)$ is a connected undirected graph, in which $V = \{v_1, v_2,..... , v_n\}$.

Let $W = \{w_1,w_2,.....,w_n\}$. How can I prove that the undirected graph 
$(V \cup W,E^{\prime})$ is connected, where $E^{\prime} = E \cup \{(v_i,w_i) | i=1,2,....,n \}$?

Comment: Do you suppose that $V$ is connected ?

Comment: Yes $(V,E)$ is a connected graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a path between any vertices $v_iv_j$, already within $V$. If we want a path between $v_i$ and $w_j$, follow the edge from $w_j$ to $v_j$ and apply the previous, and complete the path. Between $w_i, w_j$, similarly: go to $v_i, v_j$ resp. and follow the path within $V$ and combine the two edges and that path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't understand what do you mean by "apply the previous"

Comment: That there is already a path within $V$ between edges of the form $v_i$.

Comment: Please correct me If I understood it wrong, So you mean we concatenate 3 paths i.e. 1) $v_i v_j$ 2) $v_j w_j$ 3) $w_i w_j$ and then that means the graph is connected.

Comment: Indie. The first one is a path of multiple edges in general, the others are just edges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I have framed an answer to this as: let $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $(V,E)$ and let $w_1, w_2$ in $(W)$.  Now (1) $v_1$ and $v_2$ are connected as these are in $(V,E)$  (2) there is an edge between $v_1$ and $w_1$, similarly there is an edge between $v_2$ and $w_2$. So now if we concatenate (1) and (2) then we get a path $w_1, v_1, v_2, w_2$ showing that even $w_1$ and $w_2$ are connected.